# Run an autocorrect program on a text file on python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, and I am currently working on a project. This project would be to create (among other things) a program to correct a text. I am having difficulty combining two separate ideas and parts of code together. First of all, I have been experimenting with a code to correct a word that is inputted by a user.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/pirate/spellchecker).
So far, I am using this exact code without any modifications.

My goal is to be able to read a text file and go through it and find and propose corrections for the words which are wrong, as this spellchecker code does.

I would use something like:

```
    with open('words.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split()
```

to go through the text file and split it into individual words.

Ideally, if my text said 
"Wgat is the definiton" I would want to be able to recognize wgat and correct it to what, and recognize definiton and correct to definition.

How do I combine these two ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at this:
https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

It uses probability to give the best answer without being connected to a database.

Else, you can use urllib to connect to the english dictionary website: http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt

Then find the word that is most closely related to the one inputted and then print the word in this list.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've looked at this, but I'm not sure how to add my own file to this. Like to import a file and go through it, rather than one word. I guess I am missing something

Comment: I made an edit, check if that helps. Instead of inputting the value, open the file, separate the sentence into words, and then try to use the program iterating over each word.

Comment: So would I have to add an additional loop, or just switching the user input to the file read would be enough ? Sorry if the question is dumb, I'm a newbie programmer